# How is unmanaged code run in .NET?

Tags: .net, unmanaged

How does unmanaged code run in .net?

Answer (score 8):

Most commonly, using [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services), [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163494.aspx),  or [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI).

Comment: I'd add COM to this list - since that's another common way to interface with native code from .NET.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a good overview of how .Net interoperates with unmanaged code, you could start with [An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx) on MSDN.

It discusses security, performance, and what exactly happens at the interop boundary.

There are links for further reading at the bottom.